# Allow multiple directory trees to be layered on top of each other. Is this possible?

Tags: linux, git, apache, filesystems, layer

Ok, this question requires some background. I have an apache webserver that will host a development testing site that contains a foundation directory tree- a set of folders and files.

On top of this foundation directory tree i would like another partial directory tree "layered" on top. if a file is not found in the top layer, then I want the file in the foundation layer to be looked up instead.

For my project i would need 4 partial directory trees layered on top of each other, all behaving the same way: if the file in not found in the top layer, it will look for it in the layer underneath, and if it's not there it will go to the next layer underneath that one, until it reaches the base layer.

I've been trying to hypothesize a solution for this problem and i've come up with two: either with a linux filesystem, and somehow linking directories with this proposed behavior, or possibly through the apache webserver, somehow telling apache to search for a file in a different folder if it doesn't exist- perhaps in the httpd.conf file somewhere or a custom module.

Ideally some kind of linux filesystem special folder link would be the best solution, where the folder can link to a different folder but also be able to contain folders and files within it?

Ok that's my sound like a lot of crazy, but the reason i would like this system setup is so that i can use Git branches accessible through a url. Each Git repository branch would have their own modified files in their own directory tree's and have a foundation layer of files (say the master Git branch) underneath. This way i could navigate to a url and access different branches eg: branch1.newsite.com branch2.newsite.com etc.

I've put a lot of thought into this and have a near working model except for this one last caveat of layering directory trees on top of each other. Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: A Git branch contains a complete set of files.  Why not just check out each branch into a separate directory in the usual way, and put all those separate branch directories in your Apache document root?  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this layering scheme; if you have one directory with a bunch of branches somehow layered into it, how would someone specify which branch they want to access?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS

*"[Unionfs] allows files and directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system."*